# Using 'safely' to wrap a stepAIC function

Tags: r, purrr

I have some models that sometimes return an error on stepAIC. Since they run inside a loop, I want to wrap the function so that it doesn't crash the loop.

```
library(purrr)
m <- lm(mpg ~ wt + cyl + vs, data = mtcars)
step<- stepAIC(m)
step_safe<- safely(stepAIC(m))
```

For some reason, this doesn't work..
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close but you need to use safely on a function alone and apply our arguments on the newly created function:

```
safe_stepAIC = safely(stepAIC)
L = safe_stepAIC(m)
```

The function returns a list with 2 compontents: `$result` if there are no problems and `$error` if an error occured.

```
> L
$result

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ wt + cyl, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           wt          cyl  
     39.686       -3.191       -1.508  


$error
NULL
```

Comment: Thanks! But this means that I have to interact with it differently later on in the code?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how you will use it but in your code you can use `safe_stepAIC(m)$result`. If an error occurs this will result in `NULL` and this might be ok. However if your prefer and `NA` value when thing fail you can modify the function to `safe_stepAIC = safely(stepAIC, other=NA)`